# How to dynamically insert data in a list in Python?

Tags: c, python-2.7

What would be the Python equivalent for the following code written in C?

```
int a[100];
int lim;
scanf("%d",&lim)
for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here

```
# create an empty list
a = [];
# take limt as input
lim = raw_input("Enter limit")

# this is python style of for loop
# here i will start from 0 and will go upto limit
for i in range (0, int(lim)):
    # take input from user one by one and append to list
    elem = raw_input("")
    a.append(int(elem))
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `raw_input()` takes a **string** not an **integer**.

Comment: there are no types in python

Comment: What are you talking about? Python **runs** on types. Also, lists don't have the method `.add()`.

Comment: Adding some commentary on how this works would make this answer more useful. SO is about learning, not just solving problems.

Comment: @aj8uppal sorry i meant to say there are no static types in python. Also I edited my answer appropriately

Comment: @Machavity added comments !

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent:

```
lim = int(raw_input("Enter the limit: ")
a = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(lim)]
```

This takes integer input as the number of inputs we want, and then uses list comprehension to add them to a list.